Perfect squares from sum of digits
A $3$-digit number $ABC$ is Italian if
$\left(ABC + CBA\right)$ is a perfect square and $C$ and $A$ are not $0$: How do I find all Italian numbers ?.
I am still a beginner on Number Theory
$$
\mbox{but I got to}\quad 101\left(A + C\right) + 20B\quad \mbox{is}\quad n^{2}
$$
I don't know how to proceed from here.
Could we módulo to help ?.

The total cases are $9\cdot10\cdot9$, but if you look at the last digit of $101(A+B)+20B$ you can delete several cases

Numbers $k$ such that $k$ plus the reversal of $k$ is a square are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A061230

Yes, we can do modulo to help. I considered the relation $101(A+C)+20B=n^2$ modulo 20 and got
$$101(A+C)+20B=n^2 \\ A+C\equiv n^2\mod20 \\ A+C\in \{0, 1, 4, 5, 9, 16\}\mod 20 \\$$
But as $1\leq A\leq 9$ and $1\leq C\leq 9$, $2\leq A+C\leq 18$ so we obtain $\boxed{A+C\in\{4, 5, 9, 16\}}$.
We put this into our first equation and obtain
$$\left[ \begin{array}{c}404+20B=n^2\\ 505+20B=n^2\\909+20B=n^2\\ 1616+20B=n^2\end{array}\right.$$
As $1\leq B\leq 9\leftrightarrow 20\leq 20B\leq 180$, we can just check all perfect squares "around" 404, 505, 909 and 1616.
We find that the solutions are $(B_1, n_1)=(4, 22), (B_2, n_2)=(6, 25)$ and $(B_3, n_3)=(9, 33)$, which yield us all Italian numbers 143, 164, 198, 242, 263, 297, 341, 362, 396,461, 495, 594, 693, 792 and 891.

Thank you so much for your explanation. I just have one more question. Why is the set A+C = (4,5, 9 and 16)? What about the other elements like 6, 12...?

@user, those other numbers aren't squares modulo $20$.

5 mod 20 is 5, which isn't a square either...

@user, but $5^2\equiv5\bmod{20}$, so five is a square modulo $20$ – it's the square of five.
